# ffmpeg scale input image

Tags: image, ffmpeg, overlay

I use ffmpeg for overlay one image to another. 
Now I'm using cmd:

```
 ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -i banana.png -filter_complex overlay=5:H-h-5 -shortest out.png
```

it looks like this :
[image]

I need to scaling top image without scaling background image, like this :

[image]

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -i banana.png -filter_complex [1]scale=W:H[w];[0][w]overlay=5:H-h-5[v] -map "[v]" out.png
```

W and H should be replaced with the required width and height of the top image.

Comment: Thank you! please fix typo: write "," instead ";"

Comment: It's correct. A new filterchain is separated by `;`

Comment: So with ; I have error: Filter scale has an unconnected output
[0][w]overlay=5:H-h-5: command not found. With comma it works fine.
ffmpeg version 3.1.1

Comment: Added explcit pads.

Comment: It works fine, but now I need scaling both images - top and output. Tell me please how can I I it?